# no static method with name='getMessage' signature='()Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Trying write Unity plugin into Android Studio...

```
public class My_Plugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        mContext = this;
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
        getMessage(telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName());
    }

   public static String getMessage(String message){
       return message;
   }
}
```

1 class imported as AAR lib.

In Unity only 2 lines of code. Seen below

```
AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.eppz.myplugin.My_Plugin");
        GetComponent<Text>().text = pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage");
```

And Error Log:

```
I/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getMessage' signature='()Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
                                          java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getMessage' signature='()Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
                                              at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr clazz, IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at UnityEngine.AndroidReflection.GetMethodMember (IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, Syst
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `getMessage` function from Java takes a string parameter. You must call it with a string argument.

```
pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage");
```

should be:

```
pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage", "my parameter");
```